# Can't perform 'text' command from C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, full-text-search

I'm trying to perform full text search with MongoDb 3.
This query works fine for me:

```
var q = new QueryDocument(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(string.Format("{{ $text: {{ $search: {0} }} }}", JsonConvert.ToString(query.Query)));
return await context.Books.Find(q).ToListAsync();
```

But now I want to sort results by relevancy using textScore field.
I'm trying to use a such code:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Search<T>(this IMongoDatabase database, string search)     where T : class, new()
        {
            var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
            {
                { "text", typeof(T).Name },
                { "search", search }
            };
            var commandResult = await database.RunCommandAsync<TextSearchQueryResult<T>>(    textSearchCommand);

            return commandResult.Ok ? commandResult.Results.OrderBy(t => t.Score).Select(t => t.    Record) : null;
        }

class TextSearchQueryResult<T> : CommandResult
{
    public TextSearchQueryResult(BsonDocument response)
        : base(response)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<TextSearchResult<T>> Results
    {
        get
        {
            var results = Response["results"].AsBsonArray.Select(row => row.AsBsonDocument);
            var resultObjects = results.Select(item => item.AsBsonDocument);

            return resultObjects.Select(row => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<TextSearchResult<T>>(row));
        }
    }
}

public class TextSearchResult<T>
{
    public T Record { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

Launching this command I'm getting a such error:

```
Command text failed: no such command: text
```

Another approach I found:

```
return await context.Books
                    .Find(Builders<Book>.Filter.Text(query.Query))
                    //.Project(Builders<Book>.Projection.Include(new StringFieldDefinition<Book>("textScore")))
                    .Sort(Builders<Book>.Sort.MetaTextScore("textScore"))
                    .ToListAsync();
```

But in this case I'm getting a such error:

```
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys (code: 17287)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible approach using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/).

```
var pipeline = new List<BsonDocument>
{
    BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{ $match: { $text: { $search: " + JsonConvert.ToString(query.Query) + " } } }"),
    BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>("{ $sort: { score: { $meta: \"textScore\" } } }")
};

var result = await context.Books.AggregateAsync(new BsonDocumentStagePipelineDefinition<Book, Book>(pipeline));
return await result.ToListAsync();
```

As I can see the result differs from my previous approach. And seems is close to relevant result.